# Reusable view in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two web apps written in Laravel, appA and appB. Both are in different domains, exampleA.com and exampleB.com.
appA is a news website which needs members to register and login to read the news.
appB is an authentication service with its login/registration views, database and api.

What I would like to do is to connect/combine the appB into appA, so the appA uses the view of appB without moving out of exampleA.com. It means to reuse the view of one application in another. This way I can scale and construct appA by bringing more services with already developed views.
(I looked at micorservices, but they use API, what I need is more of combination of microsites).

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your two apps both use the same database structure, but you don't want them to share data, I'd recommend you looking into Tenanti https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti. Here you can setup a 'company' at boot, which can be used to point at different CSS/JS/Databases etc. or you can set them up to use the same attributes.

I would recommend using a 3rd database to define your `users` which will be domain-A and domain-B

Otherwise, if you literally want both domains to point at the same database, interfaces and codebase, I'd recommend changing the DNS records of domain-B to match domain-A